# Not too sure why this Prepared Statement isn't working

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, prepared-statement

For some reason this just isn't inserting into my database...

**HTML**

```
<form name="testimonials_form" method="post" action="insert/">
  Name
  <input type="text" name="from" maxlegnth="100" />
  Location
  <input type="text" name="where" maxlegnth="100" />
  Text Snippet
  <input type="text" name="text" maxlegnth="255">
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Continue" />
</form>
```

**PHP**

```
<?php

$from = $_POST['from'];
$where = $_POST['where'];
$text = $_POST['text'];

if (!$from || !$where || !$text) {
  $error = "You have missed some fields.";
  $solution = "Please go back and <a href=\"javascript:history.go(-1)\" target=\"_self\">try again</a>.";
} else {
  $data_array = array(':from' => $from, ':where' => $where, ':text' => $text);

  $insert_testimonial = $connect->prepare("
  INSERT INTO `testimonials` (
      text, from, where
  ) VALUES (
      :text, :from, :where
  )
  ");

  $insert_testimonial->execute($data_array);

  $amount = $insert_testimonial->rowCount();

  if ($amount < 1) {
    $error = "Something went wrong.";
    $solution = "Please go back and <a href=\"javascript:history.go(-1)\" target=\"_self\">try again</a>.";
  } else {
    header ("Location: ../");
  }
}

?>
```

All I keep getting back is my custom error "Something went wrong." so there's no 500 error (internal server error) and if I echo $from, $where and $text it displays what I typed in the form, I've re-written it about 5 times in case I wrote it wrong or something but still no luck. I know there can't be a symbol missing or in the wrong place since it would return a 500 error.

Does anyone have any clue as to what's up with it? I've written codes like this countless times but this just doesn't seem to be working, so I must be missing something.

Comment: Did you check `errorCode`?[DOC](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.errorcode.php)

Comment: Have you tried it with [`bindParam()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php)? Also, as @Shiplu states, you should be checking for error codes or [error information](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.errorinfo.php).

Comment: Just tried `bindParam` as well, tried it with both named placeholders and marked placeholders and still nothing. As for the error info I'm getting this back: `Array ( [0] => 42000 [1] => 1064 [2] => You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'from, where, text) VALUES...` that's with this code: `print_r($insert_testimonial->errorInfo());`

Comment: I believe `from` and `where` needs to be `\`from\`` and `\`where\``, as `from` and `where` are a [reserved word in MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html). Those are backticks, btw. IMO, you'd be better off not using those words as column names.

Comment: @JaredFarrish That could be a possible answer

Comment: Please look at the other examples in the http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php

Comment: I didn't think MySQL supported named parameters.

Comment: @JaredFarrish I've tried that and still brings back an error, just to be safe I've even changed every instance of from to name and altered the DB col name too. With the changes I am now getting the error `Array ( [0] => 42000 [1] => 1064 [2] => You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'where, text) VALUES ('Customer 3', 'Mars', 'Awesome!')' at line 1 )` - also, thanks for everyones suggestions so far! EDIT: Just noticed the 'where' too, I'll go change that also!

Comment: This: `right syntax to use near 'where, text)`. See the `where` in there? It should be `\`where\`` (my original unedited comment didn't have that, btw).

Comment: Yeah just altered it also! Thank you very much, if you wish to reply as that with an answer I'll mark it as correct! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from, where
```

in your query need to be

```
`from`, `where`
```

as `from` and `where` are a reserved words in MySQL:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html

Those are backticks, by the way. IMO, you'd be better off not using those words as column names, but if you do, you most often need to use backticks.